# How to Create Rounded Corner Hexagon in photoshop using polygon tool?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

**How to Create Rounded Corner Hexagon in photoshop using polygon tool ?**

[image: **Image example**]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With the Polygonal Tool selected, click the little **gear icon** on the **Control Bar** a and then check the **Smooth Corners** option.

Photoshop CC or CS6:

[image: smooth corners]

Photoshop CS5 or CS4:

[image: CS5]

You may also need to adjust the "Star" options....

[image: star]

Comment: Which Photoshop do you use ?

Comment: That's a screen shot from Photoshop CC, but it looks identical in Photoshop CS6.

Comment: I have CS4 , is there anyway for that version? thank you scott for your fast response =)

Comment: @ahmedamro check the updated answer.

Comment: Sorry , it makes a circle instead of hexagon ? Do you have any idea pleas why !

Comment: You are drawing the shape too small then. Draw a bigger shape, then reduce it after it's drawn.

Comment: How did you make those control points on the shape ?

Comment: @ahmedamro simply look at the settings in the final screenshot.

Comment: I also have the same problem...it draws a circle instead of a hexagon :| No matter how big the shape

Comment: I had to turn on "Star 1%" in CS4 to get a hexagon instead of a circle.

Comment: It makes edges a way toooo rounded! How to make edges less rounded?

Comment: I tried to make a 433x500px hexagon, but it always draws basically an oval. Star indent isn't helpful, it distorts it way too much when it starts to become noticeable.

Comment: Same problem as @Green. Edges are too rounded. Unable to reduce the roundness.

Comment: In PS 2020, there is now an input box next to the gear icon that will let you specify the pixel size of your rounded corners

Answer (score 0):

i have a idea, try this
create Hexagon, add thick border from style as shown in image,
and follow the instruction **2** and **3**
[image]

Comment: Those corners are not rounded for any practical purposes.