# Photoshop CC polygon tool with smooth corners

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes

Is there a way to create a polygon(<4 sides in my case) with rounded edges? I have tried giving it an outside stroke also, but that only works when it is a thick stroke. What I do need is a hexagon with a thin(2 pt.) stroke, with rounded edges. Please help!!

Thanks

Comment: This is a duplicate, look at this thread: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/19233/how-to-create-rounded-corner-hexagon-in-photoshop-using-polygon-tool

Comment: Hey..I have tried both the methods that are mentioned there. The first one is giving me a shape with slight indentation in the edges(even though I kept the indentation percentage as 1%) and also, I cannot control the roundness of the edges. The second method does not work for me because as I mentioned before, it only works when you have a thick border around your shape. What I need is a shape with a thin stroke. I guess the only solution would be to create it on Photoshop and import it as shape layer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Illustrator is much more efficient when creating custom shapes but if you want to use Photoshop I suggest you try the following script:

Download this script: [Corner Editor](https://photoshopscripts.wordpress.com/2013/02/03/corner-editor-photoshop-script/)

Move "Corner Editor.jsx" to "/Presets/Scripts/" in the Photoshop directory.

Re-open Photoshop

Create your shape using the Polygon Tool (U)

[image: options 1]

run the script: "File -> Scripts -> Corner Editor"

[image: options 2]

Select the options which will work for you. You can then add a layer style to give the shape a stroke.

Comment: Whewwww!!!! Thank you soo very much! Finally it works! :)